# How to reject student if they don't have a course prerequisite completed

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I am working on the above university database and am wondering how to enforce the prerequisite table. I have it so that each crs_code has a prerequisite relating to crs_requires. However, I need to figure out a way so that when a student goes to enrol in a class it will check whether they have the required prerequisite in order to enrol. If the student does have the prerequisite it should just create the new row and let them enrol, if the student does not have the required prerequisite a table should show which course they are trying to get into and which course they need.

Here is an example of some of the data in the prerequisite table:

```
+----------+--------------+
| crs_code | crs_requires |
+----------+--------------+
| 10       | 1            |
| 11       | 10           |
| 14       | 11           |
| 15       | 11           |
| 20       | 11           |
| 16       | 13           |
| 17       | 13           |
| 18       | 13           |
| 21       | 13           |
```

EDIT: The student has all of their courses in the enrolment table (both previously taken and currently taken courses) They are assigned a credit of 1 if they passed the class and credit 0 if they are currently in the class or failed it. How can I check to see if they have the credit for the prerequisite course that is needed before they enrol in a course that requires a particular prerequisite?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does it have to exist in the prerequisite table at all if it doesn't have a prerequisite?

Comment: You are right no it does not. It only has to exist in the prerequisite table if the course has a prerequisite.

Comment: You have a problem in your prerequisite table modeling. If you want to know about it let me know.

Comment: @EmmadKareem yes that would be great if you could tell me what the issue is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT crs.crs_code, req.crs_requires
FROM COURSE crs
    LEFT JOIN PREREQUISITES req ON req.crs_code = crs.crs_code
WHERE crs.crs_code = @course AND (req.crs_code IS NULL OR 
    req.crs_requires IN (SELECT crs2.crs_code FROM ENROLLMENT en2
                            JOIN SECTION se2 ON se2.sec_id = en2.sec_id
                            JOIN COURSE crs2 ON crs2.crs_code = se2.crs_code
                         WHERE en2.stu_id = @id))
```

I am assuming you will provide the Student Id and the course that the student wants to register to the query.

**EDIT**: The way I see it, a student logs in and selects a course to register, in which scenario we know both the course he wants to register to and his id. If he is eligible we let him register.

**EDIT2**: To check for credits in the prerequisite you could simply add `AND en2.Credits = 1` to the WHERE clause in the sub query (which actually checks if the student has enrolled in the prerequisite).

It seems that in MySql an [IF..ELSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) can be used only in functions or Stored procs. If you decide to go that way you could do something like

```
IF(EXISTS (a Prequisite AND the student has a particular grade/credit))
    //This student has the prereqisite. 
ELSE
    //This student does not have the required prerequisite
END
```

Comment: Is the student ID input that I am to provide suppose to go into the very last line to replace the st.stu_id?

Comment: I have edited the query to show where the student id should be supplied with @id

Comment: Made another edit to select the course code, if the student that wants to register to a course is eligible.

Comment: This currently just returns the course code that I enter when I change the @course to a course number such as 25

Comment: Yes, if the student was not eligible to take that course it would not return anything.

Comment: Is there a way to use an if statement in such a way where if the student has the credit in a prerequisite class (ex: crs_code 23) and is trying to enter into crs_code 27 it will just show a table that says "this student has the required prerequisite". If the student does not have the required prerequisite credit it would just show "This student does not have the required prerequisite.

The code you have provided does not look into what credits the student already has in the enrolment section. I have put so that if the student passed the course they get 1 credit if not they have 0.

Comment: Please check out my second edit to the answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> yes that would be great if you could tell me what the issue is

You need to pay attention to your prerequisite and course tables.

The way you have it (because the FKs are not nullable as the ERD indicates). This implies that each time you create a course, you *must* create a prerequisite course which is practically not valid. You should be able to create a course without a prerequisite if the is the case.

The same issue appears with other tables as well. This could also affect the delete to act like delete cascade.

Comment: So how would I be able to make it so that if the course has no prerequisite then I can just leave it blank? The way I have it right now the crs_code and the crs_requires are both primary keys and cannot be null. If I make the crs_requires a foreign key then a course can only have a prerequisite but some courses require more than 1 prerequisite

Comment: In the ERD tool, you specify that you allow nulls in both keys. Now this won't work while you are defining a PK on both keys. As a result, you need to create another PK (just a sequence number will do). Also, you need to add a constraint of Unique Index on the 2 columns together to prevent row duplication.